# How to use getElementsByClassName in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, clientscript

Here's the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <body>
     <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="c_wrapper">
          <div class="member">
             <form name="f1">
             </form>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript

```
var c_wrapper = document.getElementById("c_wrapper");
var mem = c_wrapper.getElementsByClassName("member");
var f = mem.lastChild;
```

When I log out variable 'f.tagName' to the console,I get the result of undefined value. What's wrong with this?

Do I need to get the outer-most element first?

Comment: [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which has no property `lastChild`

Comment: Based title + self-awareness. You don't see this every day...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a263tnsj/

Answer (score 2):

getElementsByClassName returns an **array-like object** of all child elements. lastChild is a property of a **node**

---

You should be doing lastChild on a node

```
var f = c_wrapper.lastChild
```

with HTML (I just removed the whitespaces for illustration so that you don't get blank text nodes)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="c_wrapper"><div class="member"><form name="f1"></form></div></div>
</div>
```

---

Or using indices to get the last element in the array.

```
var f = mem[mem.length - 1]
```